# Ansible passing variable for a jinja template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I try to passing argument varaible for jinja template

#### main.yml

```yaml
    - name: main
      include_tasks: "task.yml"
      tags:
        - role_aa
```

#### task.yml

```yaml
    - name: template jinja
      vars:
        - aa: {{ aa}}
      template:
        src: "{{ env }}/templates/etc/aa.conf.j2"
        dest: "/etc/aa.conf"
        owner: "root"
        group: "root"
```

#### aa.conf.j2

```
    int = {{ aa }}
```

```
ansible-playbook main.yml --extra-vars "aa=3" --tags role_aa
```

but there is no changement on template.

Comment: This is because your include does works, but your task inside won't run unless it has the `role_aa` tag. (Among other issues like the fact that you defined `vars` all wrong in the *task.yml*. you are providing here as example). You might want to read our help page [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You should remove

```
vars:
    - aa: {{ aa}}
```

as mentionned in comments

so your file task.yml will look like

```
    - name: template jinja
      template:
        src: "{{ env }}/templates/etc/aa.conf.j2"
        dest: "/etc/aa.conf"
        owner: "root"
        group: "root"
```

If ansible know the variable **aa** in his scope, it will be recognized in the jinja template automatically